# sed command to find a string but replace that line with another line.?

Tags: sed, java-home

I am using chef recipes for setting java_home. For that i am using sed command for finding JAVA_HOME string in bash_profile and then going to replace that line with

```
export JAVA_HOME="a/b/java"
```

so how to replace that line with sed command.

Answer (score 3):

This should work whether or not `JAVA_HOME` is found

```sh
sed -i '/JAVA_HOME/d;$aexport JAVA_HOME="a/b/java"' .bash_profile
```

Comment: +1; just to make it explicit: this will always place the line at the _end_ of the file; OSX (FreeBSD) version: `sed -i '' -e '/JAVA_HOME/d;$a\'$'\n''export JAVA_HOME="a/b/java"' .bash_profile`

Comment: Hi steven,

I am having another query. If i want to use command at replacement variable. e.g

sed -i '/namenode/cnamenode=for a in `cat value.txt | grep namenode | cut -d "=" -f2`; do echo $a; done' output.txt

I am runing this command but it is replacing the line with "namenode=for a in `cat value.txt | grep namenode | cut -d "=" -f2`; do echo $a; done"

but actually i want "namenode=8080"

Answer (score 2):

Another `sed`,

```
sed -i.bak '/JAVA_HOME/s@.*@export JAVA_HOME="a/b/java"@' .bashrc
```

Comment: Hi sat ..it's not working when there is no matches found. I want to insert whether java_home is set or not.